# Area inside another area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC and have one area. How can I put another area into the area. If I create an Area folder inside the existing area there is no profit.

Comment: If you are trying to resolve only routing issues, look at AttributeRouting in MVC

Comment: @Murali It's unclear what you're tring to said. Can you give more detailed answer?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv is asking why you want to have areas inside another area.

Comment: @Murali Because I've a Doc Area for Documentation in my project.  I want to add two subares of the Doc area, for instance, Functions and DataStrutures. I want to represent of adding of this two subares as additional `/Doc/{Subareaname}/{Something_else}`